# What's the skewed-t distribution?

Tags: garch, skewness, t-distribution, skew-normal-distribution

I have just learned GARCH model. One condition distribution of it is "sstd". One question of my coursework is to justify if the conditional distribution is skewed. I have seen another example sheet and it says the skew parameter must equal to one if the distribution is symmetric. I don't know why it is equal to 1 and I really don't what is a skewed-t distribution here.

Comment: This could be about a noncentral t distribution.  For example when you have two normal distributions with the same variance the t statistic will have a central t distribution under the null hypothesis that the means are equal.  The central t is symmetric.  When the means differ the t statistic has a noncentral t distribution which is not symmetric.  Skewness measures the degree of asymmetry. But when the distribution is symmetric the skewness is 0 (for this example).  I don't know how this would come up when dealing with GARCH models.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, in GARCH models the distribution would be centered at zero but potentially skewed. Monier, see section 2.3.4 of the R package "rugarch" [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) and also check out help files of relevant functions (perhaps `ugarchspec`) in that package.

Comment: @RichardHardy If the distribution is t and centered at 0 how can it be skewed? Just after equation 62 on the page describing the t distribution it says that the skewness is 0.

Comment: This is on page 17 just after equation 62.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I should look at the details before commenting further, but in general I do not see why skewness should be anyhow related to noncentrality.

Comment: You can find answers among https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=skew+t and on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewed_generalized_t_distribution

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I have found the definition of the skewed distribution. Here the "skewed parameter" is not skewness.

Comment: Please cite the source from which this was taken.

Comment: This is another way of introducing skewness into a distribution than the one I referenced in a comment after the Question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like skew-t is used as name for different distributions. The mostly used one (I believe) is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewed_generalized_t_distribution, while the answer by @Monier is another one.

A Azallini introduced a general way of "skewing" a distribution, start with some density function $f$ (such as standard normal or $t_\nu$) symmetric about zero and transform it by $$2 f(x) F(\alpha x)$$ (where $F$ is the cdf corresponding to $f$), and $\alpha$ is a new transform parameter modeling the skewness.  Observe that when $\alpha=0$ we get back $f$, since by symmetry $F(0)=1/2$. The skew normal case is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution.  Many other symmetric distribution families can be skewed the same way, and location and scale parameters can be added.

For the skew normal case there is many posts on this site, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+skew+distribution+normal+answers%3A1+

Comment: Are these method of defining skewness equivalent, or it depends on what definition do you choose. If so, what is the most accepted way to generate a skewed distribution?

Comment: @WakemeUpNow:. You could ask that as a new question, and fererence back here ...

Comment: Okay, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/612471/what-is-the-proper-way-to-define-skew-distribution