# What is the proper way to define skew distribution?

Tags: skewness, skew-normal-distribution

From [What's the skewed-t distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276327/whats-the-skewed-t-distribution/365400?noredirect=1#comment1137516_365400) there seems to be multiple way of defining skew distributions. However I am not sure if these methods are equivalent

The original questions show methods from

1. [C. Fernandez and M. Steel (1998)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241722125_On_Bayesian_Modeling_of_Fat_Tails_and_Skewness)
2. [P. Theodossiou (1998)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=65037) - which is the basis of [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewed_generalized_t_distribution), and [this R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sgt/vignettes/sgt.pdf)
3. [A. Azzalini (1985)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4615982)

In `scipy.stats`, the package implement [`scipy.stats.skewnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html#scipy.stats.skewnorm), and [`scipy.stats.skewcauchy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewcauchy.html) however, it is based on Azzalini, and Theodossiou method respectively which define *skewed parameter* differently

So I am wondering if these method of defining skew distribution equivalent? If not, what is the generally most accepted way of defining skew distribution?

### Update 1

At least I don't think they are. I tried using method 2, and 3 then minimize the equivalent coefficient, and plug it back in. The plot suggest they are different

[image: Log Distributions plot]

Reproduction code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def logp_skew_cauchy_v1(xs, mu, sigma, alpha):
    # A. Azzalini (1985)
    return (
        np.log(2) + stats.cauchy.logpdf((xs - mu)/sigma, loc=0, scale=1) +
        stats.cauchy.logcdf(alpha*(xs - mu)/sigma, loc=0, scale=1) - np.log(sigma)
    )

def logp_skew_cauchy_v2(xs, mu, sigma, lam):
    # P. Theodossiou (1998)
    return stats.skewcauchy.logpdf((xs - mu)/sigma, a=lam) - np.log(sigma)

xrange = np.linspace(-50, 50, 1001)
mu, sigma = 0, 1
eps = 0.01
lams = np.linspace(-1 + eps, 1 - eps, 1000)

matched_alphas = np.zeros_like(lams)
result_func_vals = np.zeros_like(lams)
for idx, lam in tqdm(enumerate(lams), total=len(lams)):
    target = logp_skew_cauchy_v2(xrange, mu, sigma, lam)
    result = minimize(lambda alpha: np.nanmean(np.abs(logp_skew_cauchy_v1(xrange, mu, sigma, alpha) - target)), 0, method = 'Nelder-Mead')
    if result.success:
        matched_alphas[idx] = result.x[0]
        result_func_vals[idx] = result.fun
    else:
        matched_alphas[idx] = np.nan
        result_func_vals[idx] = np.nan
        
idx = 700
plt.plot(xrange, logp_skew_cauchy_v2(xrange, 0, 1, lams[idx]), label=f"P. Theodossiou (1998) - a = {lams[idx]:.3f}")
plt.plot(xrange, logp_skew_cauchy_v1(xrange, 0, 1, matched_alphas[idx]), label=f"A. Azzalini (1985) - alpha = {matched_alphas[idx]:.3f}")
plt.title("Log distribution plot")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know if those distributions are equivalent so i want post this as an answer, but I don't think there is proper or improper eat to define skewed distribution. Summer might have numerical it computational advantages, other night be simpler to work with analytically etc. If some distributions aren't equivalent then you just have 2 different distributions either of them might fit your data better or worse, so you cannot say if one of them is less or more propper

Comment: There's an infinite variety if distinct ways to 'introduce skew' to some family of distributions